# What is the proper construction of this question - "...for who are we" or "...for who we are"?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order, questions

What is the proper way of asking the question?

***Who is to blame for who we are?***

or

***Who is to blame for who are we?***

Comment: I reopened this post because the answers on the other post describe subject–auxiliary inversion in interrogative main clauses, and the lack thereof in declarative main clauses, but the examples in this question are neither of those things.

Comment: Both the matrix and subordinate clauses are interrogatives. The first example is correct since the subordinate clause does not exhibit subject-auxiliary inversion. The meaning is "Who is to blame for the answer to the question 'Who are we?"'

Comment: The second would only be correct if "who are we" was in quotes and the questioner was referring to some quoted material, "Who is to blame for 'Who are the Boomers'?"

Answer (score 2):

"Who are we?" is a direct question, and can be repeated in a direct quote:

> Tommy jumped to his feet and shouted, "Who are we?!"

In the same way it's entirely possible to quote it as part of a general question:

> Who is to blame for "Who are we?"

but you'd have to really use your imagination to come up with a scenario where this makes sense.

Otherwise, as an ordinary question, you only need to invert the main question word.  The rest of the sentence is a *phrase* that modifies "blame"

> Who is to blame for **what's going on in the government**?
>
> Who is to blame for **where we chose to keep the safety equipment**?
>
> Who is to blame for **who we are today**?

Comment: You can say, "**What's going on in the government?**" thus it is a bad example.

Comment: @SovereignSun I'm not sure what you mean.  "What's going on in the government?" is perfectly fine ... although now that I think on it I'd be more likely to say something like, "What's going on **with** this government?"

Comment: These are two different questions, as you know "**in**" and "**with**" are quite different prepositions. I meant to say that you should explain why the subordinate clause can't act on its own in the "**Who is to blame for...**" example sentences.

Comment: Notice that in 1. You can use the subordinate as a direct question. In 2. You need to add the helping verb and put the verb in the present to make it direct. In the 3. We need to simply swap the verb and the pronoun to make it a direct question.